# .NET and Pick Database D3

Tags: .net, pick, multivalue-database

I want to connect my .net application with D3 pick database 9.0 (Windows version). In Earlier days, people used ODBC driver from Pick to write VB6 applications connecting with D3. Can I use same driver for .NET application? Pick also provides .NET API for .NET and D3 connectivity.

What confuses me is what's the difference between ODBC driver and .NET API? Is .NET API a replacement of ODBC driver for .NET or it is a further abstraction over ODBC for .NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something you are missing. With the ODBC Driver D3 comes with something called the Class Library that are compiled in Visual Basic 6. You can still use those with no problems, but you will have to use COM Interop that adds a tier and then ODBC that does add another tier itself.

As noted before I recommend using the .NET API. I have used it and the only thing I have found is that is a little bit messy, so I just created a library from that to have dynamic matrices like m[2,3,2] and retrieve the actual value of the 'sub value'.

Answer (score 1):

ODBC driver is a *universal* driver which can be used by any client which supports it. .NET API (ADO.NET driver) is a *specific* driver implementing ADO.NET interface created by Microsoft. Perfomance of ado.net drivers is usually better than ODBC driver.
So, both ODBC and ADO.NET are drivers, just different. If you plan to work solely on .net I recommend to use .NET driver, it will give you a much better experience.

Answer (score 0):

I certainly believe you should be able to use the same driver.

The difference is that the D3 .NET API makes the rich features of D3 available to you from within Visual Studio, whereas the ODBC driver looks after the actual connectivity.

The D3 .NET API is a DLL which you can plug into your .NET project. Doing so then makes many features of the D3 DBMS available to you from within Visual Studio, not only TCL commands and ACCESS statements but a whole suite of functions which enable you to read, manipulate and write data back to D3. It basically leverages .NET with a whole range of functions which understand the multivalue data model.

You can download it here:

http://www.tigerlogic.com/tigerlogic/pick/support/patches/mvsp.jsp

And the ODBC Client here:

http://www.tigerlogic.com/tigerlogic/pick/support/patches/index.jsp

Some useful documentation is also available to get you started.

Comment: By ODBC Driver I mean the "D3 class Library" that connects to D3 via RPC. As of D3 10.x it is no longer supported (ODBC itself *is* still supported) that have a COM Interface. The .NET API as you call it is the MVSP Toolkit that can be accessed via .NET or Java in Windows and it is *TIED* to the MVSP version on the D3 DBMS you have installed. You cannot use one version of DLL with the incorrect or unpatched version of the corresponding MVSP server. The patches come from Rocket themselves.